# number of roundtrip times

Tags: network-protocols

I came across this formula for finding the number of round trip times required to send a file from station A to station B
  no. of RTT's=log(filesize)+1

Can anyone clarify this formula?I mean is it a correct formula? and where does this formula come from?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is by no means accurate and you cannot predict the exact number of RTT's, only for the perfect case and there are various variables you need to consider. I suppose it refers to complexity, being O(log(filesize)). And maybe you refer to the TCP algorithm for slow start-congestion avoidance.

The alogrithm slow start-congestion avoidance was designed for a node to react to network congestion and help solve it while at the same time use the maximum possible bandwidth as fast as possible. A trade-off for these two needs.

As a fast and simple explanation, when a node sends data, in TCP, it will send one segment and wait until the other node sends an ACK, then it will double the number of TCP segments sent without receiving an ACK. It will send 2 segments, when an ACK is received, it sends 4 segments wihtout ACK. It will send 1,2,4,8 ... with an exponential formula until a timeout occurs (where no ACK was received).

Supposing there is not ACK, the number of RTT's would be O(log(filesize)). Considering an MTU (Maximum Transfer Unit) of 1500 octets, with 40 Bytes for IP and TCP headers, the Maximum Segment Size will be 1460 Octets (Bytes). If the file is 14600 Bytes, the number of round trips for the transfer will roughly be 4 without considering the round trip for 3-way handshake and without considering the connection close. This, if there is not timeout.

Regarding time, you also need to consider transmission time among other considerations. My explanation does not include more complex cases, as delayed acknowledgement, different initial congestion windows, slow server, etc.